# Limit of a multivariable function(advanced)

Tags: calculus, limits

I've been trying to find the limit of a multivariable function
[image]

Firstly, I used equivalency

[image]

and after simplifications I got 
[image]

Then, I figured it would make sense to switch to polar system.

[image]

Though after simplifications I'm back to square one. Nothing points to the fact that this can have a limit untied to a. So, is this even the right way to solve this kind of limits? I would really appreciate any help regarding the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of your equivalencies is missing a 1:  $(1+\alpha)^n\sim 1+n\alpha$.

In the polar system, if you can show that for two choices of $a$ the limit as $p\to 0$ is different, then the limit as $(x,y)\to 0$ does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Call the function $f(x,y).$ Evaluate $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x,0), \lim_{y\to 0} f(0,y).$